# Configuration page in Modal Forms not working

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

I already install Modal Forms in my localhost website and it worked perfectly, but now when I installed for my online website I can’t make any change in the configuration page, always forbidden page coming when I change the configuration and save it while I am admin user [Uid=1]

Comment: Hello. Could you make title more meaningful? Also, don't add tags to title, and don't add thanks or requests for answers. Tags have their box, we know you want answers, and we assume you will be grateful, so all three are just noise that take attention from important part: what you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

In *Drupal 7*, the installer tests for compatibility with *Clean URLs* as a part of the installation process. If the environment is tested as compatible with *Clean URLs*, it will be enabled as part of the installation process and no further action is required to enable *Clean URLs*.

If you need to enable *Clean URLs* post installation, *Drupal* will run the clean URL test automatically when you navigate to the *Clean URLs* configuration page;

`Administer > Configuration > Search and metadata > Clean URLs`, show the results, and allow you to save configuration.

You can enable or disable it at a later time by following these steps:

Navigate to the Clean URLs configuration page;

`Administer > Configuration > Search and metadata > Clean URLs`.

Wait for the automated Clean URLs test to run.

Check or uncheck the *Enable clean URLs* checkbox.

Click "*Save configuration*".

Even if *Clean URLs* are successfully enabled at install-time, if you have a dedicated server you may still want to follow the steps (below) to enable the more efficient `httpd.conf` rewrite method for clean URLs. If you choose to do that, you might want to turn off *Clean URLs* while you are working on the server.

[image: clean url]

If your *clean url* is not working enable `rewrite_module` from server.

Comment: thanks for reply but Clean URL is already enabled

Comment: You don't have permission to access /main/admin/config/development/modal_forms on this server.
this is the message that appear when I'm trying to change the conflagration

Comment: is possible that happened because I installed drupal in sub-domain  like : subdomain.domain.com